# How to send html email with image background via PHPMailer?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, html-email

How to send html email with image background via PHPMailer?
I need standart html template with image backgrounds

Answer (score 1):

It's not really up to PHPMailer, it's determined by the content you provide in the message body, but  I'd suggest you stay away from image backgrounds anyway because Outlook does not support them.